# Samples for testing C/C++ grammar

Tags: c++, c, parsing

Are there any special samples pack for testing parser grammar(C/C++, yacc or something else grammar), that will cover most of C/C++ grammar features starting from simple expressions like:

```
int a;
int b;
b=a+a+b-a+b;
printf("hello");
```

or

```
template<class R, class T,
    class B1, class B2,
    class A1, class A2, class A3>
    _bi::bind_t<R, _mfi::BOOST_BIND_MF_NAME(mf2)<R, T, B1, B2>, typename _bi::list_av_3<A1, A2, A3>::type>
    BOOST_BIND(R (BOOST_BIND_MF_CC T::*f) (B1, B2), A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3)
{
    typedef _mfi::BOOST_BIND_MF_NAME(mf2)<R, T, B1, B2> F;
    typedef typename _bi::list_av_3<A1, A2, A3>::type list_type;
    return _bi::bind_t<R, F, list_type>(F(f), list_type(a1, a2, a3));
}
```

with difinitions what type of test it is(like: "this test is for checking work with pointer's").

Comment: How can you test parser grammar separate from the compiler?

Comment: Have you looked onto project sites of the obvious candidates like clang or gcc? Just out of curiosity, what do you want to do?

Comment: For example I have yacc grammar with parser. The main idea is to check grammar correctness.

Comment: There are some random C code generators out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has a lot of test-cases in the source, so if your grammar is open source under GPL, then you can use that.

Otherwise, try finding large open source projects and just feeding that through it - you'll obviously have to verify that it is correct, and since no two compilers produce the same output [whatever stage you look at it], you will have to figure out "what it's supposed to be" yourself. Or write something that can translate the intermediate files from GCC to the same format as your grammar output, and compare...

Comment: Yes, also llvm-testsuit has them. Both of them are great, but they test more compiler and codegenerator features.